# Angular: defining a module or not

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Simple Angular question.

Should I define an angular module or not? What's the difference if I do it one way or the other?

For example, what's the difference between saying `var myApp = angular.module('myFirstApp', []);` and `angular.module('myFirstApp', [])` ?

If I use the 2nd option, I understand all my factories etc have to be dot chained, correct? As in `.factory('myFactory', function() {})`. But if I use the 1st option and define the angular module, I have to define my factories etc too? as in `myApp.factory('myFactory', function() {
});` ?

And if I dot chain (as in the 2nd option), am I then adding everything to the global namespace of the application? But what's the difference between that and defining the module and adding everything to in this case `myApp`?

Please clarify and explain, sorry for the super simple question, I think the answer to this can tie a lot together for me.

Thank you.

Edit: I think some of my question above can be paraphrased in the following way: What's the difference between using the full angular.module() as getter each time and a global variable? Why should a global variable be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to assign your angular module to a variable. 
But you do need to define it like this.

```
angular.module('myModule', []);
```

Your factories do not have to be dot chained one after another. You can add a factory to a module like this.

```
angular.module('myModule').factory('myFactory', function() {});
```

You can use `angular.module('myModule')` to get the module and add controllers, factories, ect... to the module.

This allows you to put you controllers, factories, ect...
in different files.

I hope this guides you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is all you've wanted to know about angularjs, but was afraid to ask. :D

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

There is good practices and explanation why you should do one thing and not the other.

Your answer is in single responsibility, **Definitions (aka Setters)** section.

Answer (score 0):

No they don't have to be chained. It's very simple

`angular.module()` is both setter and getter. You provide second argument, dependency array, to set (declare)  new module

Without the second argument it is a reference to a previously declared module.

So without chaining you can do:

```
// declare new module
angular.module('myFirstApp', []);

// add features of module
angular.module('myFirstApp').controller(...;    
angular.module('myFirstApp').directive(...;
```

This is the same as doing:

```
var app =  angular.module('myFirstApp', []);

app.controller(....
app.directive(....
```

However best practices are to avoid using a global variable and use the full `angular.module()` as getter each time

it is also the same as using chaining

```
angular.module('myFirstApp', [])
     .controller(....
     .directive(....
```

Comment: Thank you. Isn't this what I mean by dot chaining? as in when you write `.controller(...;` What's the difference between doing it this way and defining the module? And then if I define the module do I have to define my services / factories etc the same way? Maybe I'm using the phase `dot chained` in the wrong way?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking

Comment: I think the way you explained it, it's a third way? in addition to the two I mention in my question?  `angular.module('myFirstApp').controller(...;` is like dot chaining but you're just adding `angular.module('myFirstApp')` before each controller or service? Whats the benefit to doing this instead of just dot chaining them?

Comment: I get your confusion, I may have commented on the wrong answer :) Ok I'll re-read everything...

Comment: Benefit is they don't need to be in same file

Comment: Thank you this is helpful. 

Can you explain "...is both setter and getter. You provide second argument, dependency array, to set (declare) new module

Without the second argument it is a reference to a previously declared module."

What is `Setter and Getter` and what is the `second argument, dependency array to declare new module` ? Sorry o.O!

And what does `Without the second argument it is a reference to a previously declared module.` mean?

Comment: `set module` vs `get module` ==> setter/getter. Common terms , look them up

Comment: Ok, and `second argument, dependency array to declare new module` ?

Comment: Ah, get it so 'ionic' or 'ui-router' or something between the `[]` is the dependency array declaring a new module as part of the first module?  And is also the setter?

Comment: no...those are module dependencies that are injected using the `dependency array`. Go through the docs and some basic tutorials

Comment: Thanks. I've done both, gone through the docs and basic tutorials, just have some clarifying questions.

Comment: But as per your example above, in the way I am reading it you're saying the `second argument` is the `dependency array`, correct?

Comment: `angular.module( name, dependency_array)`

Comment: And in your explanation above, the `second argument` you are referring to is the `name`? Sorry :D If you can answer the question as asked I'd understand it better.

Comment: suggest you read up on what arguments are in functions. You can't use angular without some reasonably solid javascript understanding

Comment: *Benefit is they don't need to be in same file* - it is much closer to drawback, in fact. `angular.module('myFirstApp')...` is the most common cause of module-related errors I've seen.

Comment: @estus `drawback` ?

Comment: @estus and why is that? Have many apps that use that as getter and have never had a problem. Also follows most common style guide recommendations  https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#style-y020

Comment: @AgentZebra defintiions of terms like arguments , getter and setter are something you will need to look up. These are extremely common programming terms. I am not trying to be condescending but in order to discuss parts of a language like javscript there are basic terms that need to be used

Comment: This kind of usage requires `angular.module('myFirstApp', [])` module definition to precede `angular.module('myFirstApp')` and strictly follow file loading order, otherwise [an error is thrown](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod). If the app consists of several files, one module per file is much stronger and well-proven strategy.

Comment: What's the difference between using `the full angular.module() as getter` each time and `a global variable`? I think that was my original question, you were able to paraphrase it in simpler terms. Why should a global variable be avoided?

Comment: @estus well that would depend on build tools used... i never have that issue

Comment: Exactly. For the app that relies on Angular modularity with no build system this becomes an antipattern, and this is where 'getter' is misused most often. For the app with build system `var app = angular.module('myFirstApp', []); app...` is more preferable than `angular.module('myFirstApp')..` just because it is more readable and minifies better with no downsides (AMD/CJS modules are IIFEs, `app` doesn't leak to global scope).

Comment: @charlietfl my apologies. You could also say by `x` I mean this piece of code in this instance, that can help. Some people have the background but it's not locked in and they need to ask questions that might seem to some as though they're absolute beginner. As I said, people understand things and piece things together in different ways. Which is why it's often helpful to answer a question in the way it was asked.